# How to make an element of such a complex shape?

Tags: css

[image]

The designer was clearly not adequate, but I wondered if it was possible to do this?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd find it a lot easier to use an image.

Comment: Since the shape is strictly geometric a SVG seems suitable: it's responsive and you could use it directly in an HTML5 document.